# How to efficiently iterate over multiple generators?

Tags: python, generator

I've got three different generators, which yields data from the web. Therefore, each iteration may take a while until it's done.

I want to mix the calls to the generators, and thought about roundrobin (Found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html)).
The problem is that every call is blocked until it's done.

Is there a way to loop through all the generators at the same time, without blocking?

Comment: I have a module that can merge your generators using threads, one sec to add a generator/iteration output

Comment: use threads? ... maybe ... GIL might break this

Comment: threads are great for weird blocking IO - they release the GIL until the remote IO returns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the `iter()` method on my [`ThreadPool`](https://github.com/lunixbochs/meta/blob/master/snippets/python/threadpool.py) class.

`pool.iter()` yields threaded function return values until all of the decorated+called functions finish executing. Decorate all of your async functions, call them, then loop through `pool.iter()` to catch the values as they happen.

Example:

```
import time
from threadpool import ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(max_threads=25, catch_returns=True)

# decorate any functions you need to aggregate
# if you're pulling a function from an outside source
# you can still say 'func = pool(func)' or 'pool(func)()
@pool
def data(ID, start):
    for i in xrange(start, start+4):
        yield ID, i
        time.sleep(1)

# each of these calls will spawn a thread and return immediately
# make sure you do either pool.finish() or pool.iter()
# otherwise your program will exit before the threads finish
data("generator 1", 5)
data("generator 2", 10)
data("generator 3", 64)

for value in pool.iter():
    # this will print the generators' return values as they yield
    print value
```

Comment: This is awesome. Is it possible to islice the generators within the code? because even if i islice the `pool.iter()` generator, the threads continue to yield all the data, which is very large in my generators (5000+ while i need only 20 results).

Comment: Can you islice the input generators?

Comment: It seems that `itertools.islice` is not recognized as a generator. Plus a little sleep is needed between each self.returned call, because if they return really fast, some of them gets lost. This is my fixed version of `threadpool.ThreadPool.worker`'s try block: http://pastebin.com/inTxx2tB

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your source generator - I can iterate over a million numbers without a sleep without any getting lost. Does putting a sleep in your generator itself fix it? That's probably a better place.

Comment: As far as the generator vs iterator issue, I just pushed a cleaner fix for it.

Comment: Thanks Man! May I ask for one last improvement? I need a way to terminate the threadpool, and ask all threads to cease tasks immediately? `self.finish()` does it, but it's blocking.

Comment: @lunixbochs: Could you please put a license on your meta/snippets directory? MIT/BSD would be appreciated.

Comment: I just licensed it as MIT.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no: there's no good way to do this without threads.

Sometimes ORMs are augmented with some kind of peek function or callback that will signal when data is available.  Otherwise, you'll need to spawn threads in order to do this.  If threads are not an option, you might try switching out your database library for an asynchronous one.